# How can i determine in which box i clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

First off i'm new to javascript and still learning its basics, i'm trying to determine in which box i clicked(canvas).
My boxes are a list of dictionaries that look like this if we use console.log to visualize them, let's call that list `labels`:

```
[
    {"id":"1","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4802","xMin":"4770","yMax":"156","yMin":"141"},
    {"id":"2","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4895","xMin":"4810","yMax":"157","yMin":"141"},
    {"id":"3","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4923","xMin":"4903","yMax":"156","yMin":"145"},
    {"id":"4","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4956","xMin":"4931","yMax":"156","yMin":"145"}
]
```

Here we can see we have 4 rectangles and their coordinates.
The function i used to get mouse clicks is :

```
canvas.addEventListener("contextmenu", getPosition, false);
function getPosition(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var x = event.x;
  var y = event.y;

  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

  x -= canvas.offsetLeft;
  y -= canvas.offsetTop;

  console.log("x:" + x + " y:" + y);
}
```

The part where i'm struggling is to find out if where i clicked are inside any of the boxes and if the click is inside one i want the id.

**What i tried:**

I tried adding this after the `console.log` in the previous code snippet:

```
for (i = 0,i < labels.length; i++) {
                if (x>labels[i].xMin) and (x<labels[i].xMax) and (y>labels[i].yMin) and (y<labels[i].yMax) {
                    log.console(labels[i].id)
                }
            }
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Have you tried `event.target`?

Comment: Maybe you should start by learning JavaScript syntax. You delimit different parts of a for loop using `;` not `,` (`for (i = 0,i.....`) and you need to use `&&` not `and`. Also, a `if` statement's condition has to be wrapped in parentheses

Comment: Can we have some HTML to make a working snippet?

Comment: Your comments regarding the syntax must be true as i'm just starting to learn it, if what i tried is logically correct and can just be adjusted to the correct syntax it'll be nice.

Comment: document.elementFromPoint(clientX, clientY) could work aswell, since event.target used to fail me on touchend events. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint

Comment: @Lain The OP is trying to get the position of images drawn on a `<canvas>` not the position of HTML elements.

Comment: Hmm indeed, you are correct. Then how does event.target provide any help? That kinda confused me :-)

Comment: Trying to get if the mouse click is inside a rectangle or not and if so which.

Answer (score 2):

The rects in Labels are all very far to the right, so probably you need to add the scroll position to the mouse position.

Made a working example (open the console to see the result):
https://jsfiddle.net/dgw0sxu5/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body{
                background: #000;
                margin: 0
            }
        </style>

        <script>
            //Some object which is used to return an id from a click
            //Added a fillStyle property for testing purposes
            var Labels = [
                {"id":"0","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4956","xMin":"0","yMax":"50","yMin":"0","fillStyle":"pink"},
                {"id":"1","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4802","xMin":"4770","yMax":"156","yMin":"141","fillStyle":"red"},
                {"id":"2","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4895","xMin":"4810","yMax":"157","yMin":"141","fillStyle":"blue"},
                {"id":"3","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4923","xMin":"4903","yMax":"156","yMin":"145","fillStyle":"limegreen"},
                {"id":"4","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4956","xMin":"4931","yMax":"156","yMin":"145","fillStyle":"aqua"}
            ];

            //Initialisiing for the testcase
            window.onload = function(){
                //The canvas used for click events
                var tCanvas = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('canvas'));
                tCanvas.width = 4956; //Highest xMax value from labels
                tCanvas.height = 157; //Highest yMax value from labels

                //The graphical object
                var tCTX = tCanvas.getContext('2d');

                //Drawing the background
                tCTX.fillStyle = '#fff';
                tCTX.fillRect(0, 0, tCanvas.width, tCanvas.height);

                //Drawing the rects for testing purposes
                //The rectangles are kinda far on the right side
                for(var i=0, j=Labels.length; i<j; i++){
                    tCTX.fillStyle = Labels[i].fillStyle;
                    tCTX.fillRect(+(Labels[i].xMin), +(Labels[i].yMin), +(Labels[i].xMax)-+(Labels[i].xMin), +(Labels[i].yMax)-+(Labels[i].yMin));
                };

                tCanvas.onclick = function(event){
                    var tX = event.clientX - this.offsetLeft + (document.body.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft), //X-Position of click in canvas
                        tY = event.clientY - this.offsetTop + (document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop), //Y-Position of click in canvas
                        tR = []; //All found id at that position (can be more in theory)

                    //Finding the Labels fitting the click to their bounds
                    for(var i=0, j=Labels.length; i<j; i++){
                        if(tX >= +(Labels[i].xMin) && tX <= +(Labels[i].xMax) && tY >= +(Labels[i].yMin) && +(tY) <= +(Labels[i].yMax)){
                            tR.push(Labels[i].id)
                        }
                    };

                    console.log(
                        'Following ids found at the position @x. @y.: '
                            .replace('@x.', tX)
                            .replace('@y.', tY),
                        tR.join(', ')
                    )
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: what exactly did not work?

`var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");` should be outside of your function to save performance at a second call.

And getting coordinates is not complicated, but complex.

There is a great resource on how to get the right ones: http://javascript.info/coordinates

Be sure about the offset measured relative to the parent element (`offsetParent` and also your `offsetLeft`), document upper left (`pageX`) or viewport upper left (`clientX`).

Comment: `elementFromPoint` won’t help here because the only element you have is your canvas

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems to be correct, you just need to fix the syntax.

```
for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    if ((x>labels[i].xMin) && (x<labels[i].xMax) && (y>labels[i].yMin) && (y<labels[i].yMax)) {
        console.log(labels[i].id)
    }
}
```

Here is a complete example:

```
labels = [
          {"id":"1","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4802","xMin":"4770","yMax":"156","yMin":"141"},
          {"id":"2","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4895","xMin":"4810","yMax":"157","yMin":"141"},
          {"id":"3","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4923","xMin":"4903","yMax":"156","yMin":"145"},
          {"id":"4","image":"1-0.png","name":"","xMax":"4956","xMin":"4931","yMax":"156","yMin":"145"}
]

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.addEventListener("contextmenu", getPosition, false);
function getPosition(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;

  var label = labels.find(function(label){
     return (x>label.xMin) && (x<label.xMax) && (y>label.yMin) && (y<label.yMax)
  });

  if(label){
     console.log("clicked label", label.id);
  }else{
     console.log("no label was clicked");
  }
}
```

Comment: it didn't work yet didn't give errors, guess i'll have to debug.

Comment: @user9686018 How are you testing it ? You've added an event listener for `contextmenu` which is the right mouse click.

Comment: @user9686018 Also, instead of `event.x` use `event.clientX`, the same goes for `y` and you can get rid of `x -= canvas.offsetLeft;`.

Comment: Correct i am using the right mouse click to test and regarding the second comment i didn't really understand it

Comment: @user9686018 I've edited my answer to add a complete example.

Comment: I think in the complete example you should replace and with &&. return (x>label.xMin && x<label.xMax && y>label.yMin && y<label.yMax)